# Finding average of numbers from one line of a file avoiding the first word

Tags: c++, io

I have a text file which has the following format:

U123 78 90 65 85

U234 87 98 90 56

U345 89 90 98 87

U456 45 56 67 78

The first value (Uxxx) is a "Student Number" and every other value on the same line is a test score (first is exam 1, second exam 2, etc.)

I am trying to get the average of all exams for a specific student (specified by the user) but am having trouble with how to store the exam values from the specific line.

I have a different function which displays the scores for a specified student and am trying to modify it to work for this as well but am having troubles. Here is the code for that function:

```
void DisplayStudentScores()
{
    string stuNum;
    ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open(scores.txt);

    //for testing purposes
    if(!inFile)     {
        cout << "File not found" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    //end of test

    cout << "Enter the Student ID of who's scores you would like to see: ";
    cin >> stuNum;
    cout << endl;

    string line;
    while(getline(inFile, line)){
        if(line.find(stuNum) != string::npos){
            cout << line << endl;
            break;
        }
        else{
            cout << "Student not found" << endl;
            break;
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to read the file once and store all of the information? What data structures are you familiar with? Arrays? `std::vector`? `std::map`?

Comment: @Beta I would only use the information until the average of the scores is printed, after that, I don't need it stored since I access the file separately for every function. I could do `std::vector` to store the numbers. I'm stuck as to how to get just the numbers for the specific student.

Comment: A vector of vectors? Or vector in the input loop? You might not even need to store the numbers since you just need to store the sum.

Comment: "I am having problems", or "I am having trouble" is not a useful problem description, or a specific question. "Hello, Mike's Auto Repait? I am having problems with my car, can you fix it?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fields are neatly separated by spaces, so the stream operator is better for this than `getline`:

```
string stu;
int score1, score2, score3, score4;
infile >> stu >> score1 >> score2 >> score3 >> score4;
```

You can put that inside a loop:

```
while(infile >> stu >> score1 >> score2 >> score3 >> score4){
  if(stu == stuNum){
    // calculate and print average
    return;
  }
}
cout << "Student " << stuNum << " not found" << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.